# Isolate service networks with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, networking

I have two containerised services, A and B, with which I wish to isolate network communications with docker compose. There is also a shared service C which is not isolated from A or B and is free to communicate with either.

[image]

I have tried to achieve this with the following docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  C:
    build: C
    depends_on:
      - A
      - B
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - A
      - B
  A:
    build: A
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - A
  B:
    build: B
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - B

networks:
  A:
    internal: true
  B:
    internal: true
```

With this, C is able to connect to both A and B on the hosts A:8080 and B:8080 respectively and  A and B are isolated as required. However, neither A nor B is able to connect to C on C:8080. Removing the network options from the compose file, all services are able to talk to each other. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't experience same issue with similar setup to what you describe. 'A' & 'B' can ping & access services on 'C' just fine. Few things to look at:

- Port aside, can you ping 'C' from either of the other containers?
- You probably shouldn't (can't?) name containers capital 'A', 'B', 'C' if you're going to build them in docker-compose. If that's what's actually used, try more meaningful names.
- Does name resolution work if you do `nslookup c` from either a & b? It should resolve via `nameserver 127.0.0.11`
- firewall on 'C' or service not up on `c:8080`?

Comment: Thanks napovi. The real hostnames and container names have just been replaced for convenience. I could ping C from either of the containers and `nslookup c` was resolved via `nameserver 127.0.0.11` as you said. The actual issue was that the service on C was listening on `localhost:8080`. Binding the service to `C:8080` worked. I'm a bit confused as the services on A and B are bound to `localhost:8080` but docker seems to automatically map them to `A:8080` and `B:8080` but does not do the same for the service on C. Do you know why this could be the case?

Comment: This is likely more down to how service listening on `:8080` is configured than Docker. Possibly it's expecting to be in default Docker subnet which is usually `172.17.0.0/16` but with two 'internal' NICs on `C`, subnets may be `172.18.0.0/16` and `172.19. 0.0/16` (or some other values). Usually services in containers would listen an all IPv4 & IPv6 NICs: take default NGINX config for example `listen 80;` and `listen [::]:80` which may not be the case in service on C.

Comment: I see, thanks for all your help.